# Would any voltage be induced in this scario due magnetic coupling?

Tags: electromagnetism, emc, interference, common-mode

Imagine a source with a 100 Ohm source impedance is coupled to an amplifier/receiver which has 1Meg input impedance and the transmission is done by using two parallel wires signal and return |XA| and |GB| in the diagram. And imagine a changing magnetic interference is varying across this page.To observe the magnetic coupling effect I use this model below:

[image]

If G was wired to J and B was wired to H, i.e if both receiver and source sides were earth grounded I can say that the voltage induced at A would be greater than the voltage induced at B because Area2+Area1 > Area1.

But what if G and J has no wire in between and similarly B and H has no wire in between, i.e they are on the air 1 meter above the earth. In this case what can we say about the magnetic interference affect? Would there still be voltage induced at A and B due to magnetic coupling?

Comment: If you imagine the flux at right angles from generating 10mA sine around the loop and we stop that and put the loop near the top of a solenoid or similar wire loop carrying some current attenuated my mutual inductance but had the same flux flowing thru this loop it should generate the same current.  Of course this depends on the mutual inductance from geometry that is not easily computed for any distance but you can imagine the greatest voltage across the 1M resistors

Comment: “Voltage induced at” technically makes no sense. Voltage is induced in series with a wire moving through a magnetic field. And, to talk about a voltage seen at a point you have to define a reference measurement point like ground or earth or 0 volts, but any node can be the reference for measurement. Also, from what I can tell of your description only the vertical parts of the circuit will have induced a voltage and, if I have read your question correctly, that means there will be a voltage difference between A and B.

Answer (score 0):

I use Vinduce = @e-7 * [Area (meters square) / Distance (Meters)] * dI/dT

Consider a lightning strike, with current rise time of 1uS to 50,000 amps.

Have a PCB with circuit area of 4" by 4" (0.1 meter by 0.1 meter), located 1 meter from the lightning rod; what is voltage induced in the circuit

Vinduce = 2e-7 Henry/meter * (0.1m * 0.1m / 1m) * 50,000 amps/uS

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 0.01 * 50 GigaAmps/second

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 1e-2 * 5e+10 = 2 * 5 * 10^(-7 -2 +100 = 10 * 10^1 = 100 volts

Can you define your own dI/dT, Area, and Distance?

The formula is a combined version of Biot_Savart and Faraday Law Induction.